# Is there anyway to fix the xclip relate with neovim "+y?clipboard: error: Error: target STRING not available

Tags: linux, clipboard, neovim, xclip

When use neovim to copy content to system clipboard with "+y way. It works well if neovim's window doesn't close, if I close neovim window, the content of + register will disappear.
for example, then if I use tow neovim, one copy someword, another can paste easily, but is the copy none close window, then paste one's :reg will show in "+ line: clipboard: error: Error: target STRING not available
This happens after I cp the whole /home to /mnt/home, and rm /home, then reboot I found the issue.

I try to reinstall xclip and neovim, didn't work. But install xsel(before I didn't install) and uninstall xclip could slove this issue. However, my tmux will use 'xclip -in -selection clipboard' So, I can't use my tmux to copy into system board. Reinstall the xclip, the neovim will choose the xclip automatically, then the clipboard broken again.
I believe this can be solved, hoping someone can solve the problem, fix the xclip issue, or provide some suggestion about tmux set xsel.

Comment: I change the .tmux.conf to`bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xsel -ib"`
then xsel replace xclip work well, but I still want to know what's really problem xclip.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open xclip issue related to `Error : target STRING not available` https://github.com/astrand/xclip/issues/38.

I recommend switching from `xclip` to `xsel`. Neovim now prefers `xsel` over `xclip` due to reports of issues. See pull request https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/9302.

> Reinstall the xclip, the neovim will choose the xclip automatically, then the clipboard broken again.

You should check your Neovim version. The change to prefer `xsel` over `xclip` was introduced in Neovim `v0.9.0`.

If you can't upgrade to `v0.9.0` then you can override the clipboard provider by setting the `g:clipboard`. See https://neovim.io/doc/user/provider.html#g%3Aclipboard for details on how to do that.

> To configure a custom clipboard tool, set g:clipboard to a dictionary. For example this configuration integrates the tmux clipboard:

```
let g:clipboard = {
  \   'name': 'myClipboard',
  \   'copy': {
  \      '+': ['tmux', 'load-buffer', '-'],
  \      '*': ['tmux', 'load-buffer', '-'],
  \    },
  \   'paste': {
  \      '+': ['tmux', 'save-buffer', '-'],
  \      '*': ['tmux', 'save-buffer', '-'],
  \   },
  \   'cache_enabled': 1,
  \ }
```